# Pass username and client certificate from apache to tomcat using mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, authorization, mod-jk

I want to authenticate web services either by ssl certificate (aimed at automatisms) or openid (aimed at people, I am using auth0 as a provider). The web services run in a tomcat container, which is behind an apache web server, using jk. The web server already authenticates the user using auth0 (an using mod_auth_openidc) for other paths, and only available through https. I also have a database which currently maps usernames provided by auth0 to roles (used for authorization in apache).

I would like to have the following functionality:

1. figure out username

   - if apache have already logged in the user, use the username
   - if a client certificate is used in the request use the DN as a username
   - if none of the above, then redirect so apache does the authentication
2. figure out the role

   - make a database lookup based on the username

I have figured out that I might have to write a Filter, and it seems from [jk's proxy documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/proxy.html) that I can get the cert and username from the request. I have written the following code:

```
package com.kodekonveyor.realm;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class KKAuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

private ServletContext context;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
    this.context.log("KKAuthorizationFilter initialized");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String user = httpRequest.getRemoteUser();
    Object cert = httpRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    this.context.log("user:"+user);
    this.context.log("cert:"+cert);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}

}
```

However when I try to reach a servlet with a user which is currently authenticated, or with client ssl authentication, both the user and cert is logged as null. I suspect I have to do some more apache configuration to make it work.
A test servlet is at /servlet/servlet in tomcat.

I have the following apache configuration (parts are omitted for brewity)

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/repo

#correct OIDC configuration omitted

<VirtualHost myhost.mydomain.com:443>
    ServerName myhost.mydomain.com

DBDriver pgsql
#other DBD configurations are omitted

JkMount /servlet* worker1

<Directory /var/www/repo/servlet>
    DirectoryIndex off
    RewriteEngine Off
    AuthType openid-connect
    AllowOverride None
    AuthzDBDQuery "a correct database query"
    Require dbd-group allrepo
LogLevel debug
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/repo>
    DirectoryIndex off
    RewriteEngine Off
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

#correct letsencrypt configuration omitted
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is found to be the fact that if you have a JkMount in a Location (or perhaps also a Directory) directive, all other autorization and authorization (or even all other?) directives are ineffective.

An example working configuration for the servlet located at /servlet:

```
<Location "/servlet*">
        JkMount  worker1
</Location>
<LocationMatch /servlet.*>
    DirectoryIndex off
    RewriteEngine Off
    AuthType openid-connect
    AllowOverride None
    LogLevel debug
    Require valid-user
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        SSLOptions +ExportCertData
        SSLVerifyClient require
</LocationMatch>
```

another possible solution:

```
<LocationMatch /servlet.*>
       SetHandler jakarta-servlet
       SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME worker1
       DirectoryIndex off
       RewriteEngine Off
       AuthType openid-connect
       AllowOverride None
       Require valid-user
       LogLevel debug
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        SSLOptions +ExportCertData
        SSLVerifyClient require
</LocationMatch>
```

See https://tomcat.markmail.org/thread/iax6picwsjlhbohd for discussion